# What changes are coming that would reduce the problems assosciated with HTTPS compared to HTTP?

Tags: web-hosting, web-development, https, security, http

I have a web site under development. It is used for surveys but there's an advertising component. As it is very new I have used almost all the latest technologies.  AngularJS, ASP.NET WebAPI 2 etc.

I am consider what I should do about HTTP and HTTPS. I want my site to appear secure and for me it's important that the user might see a lock or even better company name appearing in the browser search bar to emphasis security.

However I understand that with HTTPS there are some drawback such as the time taken to encode. Going forward is it likely that these drawbacks might become less important so that for example in 5 years time HTTPS may become more of a standard rather than exception?

Comment: There is plenty of documentation on Google :) These will anwer your questions

Comment: @Martijn -- Please don't tell anybody to go search for answers.   If it is already answered *on this site*, flag it as duplicate.   Otherwise, answer it here and link to the all the references that you can find easily on Google.

Comment: This question is asking for opinions about what will become important in the future.  There is no way to answer this question with facts, experience, or reference.

Comment: Stephen - Often things are missed by me when I don't know about what's coming. Our web site uses AngularJS and its amazing. It's the future for many but for us it is the present. I am just asking really about what might come up that people are using but that many don't know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes use HTTPS everywhere, add a HSTS policy, use only TLS, etc. HTTPS already is "the standard" and it's plenty fast enough with a proper server setup...it's just that most folks don't take the time or wanna spend the money to use it.

If you consider time to encode a drawback, consider the results of the encoding (good encryption) as a drawback too. I realize that was an example, but really, speed is the only thing one can complain about when it comes to HTTPS.

To answer the title question, HTTP2.0::SPDY would reduce the problems with HTTPS. We already have come beyond SSL2/3 into TLS, processing power is moot, and browser/OS support is wide. Mass SPDY support is a last step towards HTTPS everywhere de-facto software.